# ReAuthorize Facebook App in Parse ios SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I logged into my app using my FB credentials via the standard Parse SDK instructions. All worked fine, until I was playing with the phone settings and decided to switch off the application's fb authorization in the privacy settings in my phone.

I then couldn't log into the app using my FB credentials anymore. So I tried to remove the app from my facebook apps via facebook.com and waited a while, but still I get error:

> com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
>       body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 190;
>               "error_subcode" = 458;
>               message = "Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application xxxxxx.";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 400;
>       headers =     (
>                   {
>               name = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
>               value = "*";
>           },
>                   {
>               name = "Content-Type";
>               value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
>           },
>                   {
>               name = Pragma;
>               value = "no-cache";
>           },
>                   {
>               name = Vary;
>               value = "Accept-Encoding";
>           },
>                   {
>               name = "Cache-Control";
>               value = "no-store";
>           },
>                   {
>               name = "WWW-Authenticate";
>               value = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_token\" \"Error validating access token: The user has not authorized
>   application xxxxxxxxx.\"";
>           },
>                   {
>               name = Expires;
>               value = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
>           }
>       ); }}

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue on my phone by resetting my privacy settings. Its an issue with iOS for not flushing the privacy settings once a user de-authorizes the application. It should have just asked for permission but the didn't.